# CSS Hover Problems

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, design, meta

When hovering over a link that has the `border-bottom: 1px dotted;` rule, it doesn't remove it when adding a `text-decoration: underline;`.

Either change the `text-decoration: underline;` to a `border-bottom: 1px solid;` or add a `border-bottom: none;` to it.
[alt text http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/7445/googlechromescreensnapz.jpg](http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/7445/googlechromescreensnapz.jpg)

Comment: Blank [link](http://google.com) comment.

Comment: @Josh: It doesn't look completed to me either. (I'm on Chrome)

Comment: As am I, let me double check in Safari. Is it just me, or is Chrome the new "IE" with weird issues everyone keeps having?

Comment: Well Safari uses the same rendering engine... right? Maybe you should check Firefox?

Comment: Blah, I'm too lazy to start up that beast. They may use the same engine but I believe the implementation is a little different. Not to mention that the new rule should simply remove the text-decoration, not add a solid bottom border.

Comment: I'm seeing the change now, and the color does change. It'd still be nice to have that solid bottom border, though style however you want. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good idea; it's only an issue on comments, so relatively minor.

I added

```
.comment-text a:hover
{
    color: #6C0000;
    border-bottom: 1px #6C0000 dotted;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, that should be `solid` not `dotted` otherwise there won't be a difference between the `:link` and `:hover` states. Unless I'm misunderstanding, which is entirely possible at this time of the day (night).